# post requests to google fusion tables

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

I've been trying to insert new rows in my google fusion table, but in response I obtain a 401 error; also any other post request doesn't work.
I've already put the oauth access token, and also the api key, here is the code:

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {
             String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql= **here I put my   query** ?key="+ "**here I put my api key**";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add request header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Chrome/11.0.660.0");
    con.addRequestProperty("client_id", "**here I put my client_ID**");
    con.addRequestProperty("client_secret", "**here I put my client_secret**");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Oauth " + "**here I put my access token**");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } 

}
```

Can you tell me if the code is wrong and in which point?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two separate requests are required:

- a first POST request, to get the OAuth token. The body containing client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri, grant_type and the authorization_code.
- a second POST request with body being the SQL command. In this case, INSERT INTO TableID (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...). This request needs the Authentication header token.